# count distinct and update another table where postnr = "count distinct"

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

table 1:

```
    postnr
    ------
    11111
    11111
    11111
    22222
    33333
    33333
```

table 2:

```
    postnr    count
   --------  -------
    11111     ?
    22222     ?
    33333     ?
    44444     ?
```

What I want to do is to update table 2 with the count of each postnr from table 1.

So in this case count for 11111 would be 3, for 22222 it would be 1 and for 33333 it would be 2.

the tables reside in different databases and this is my futile attempt but it isn't generating any counts in table 2...

```
    $pdo1 = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_SERVER.';dbname='.DB_NAME_PROFILDATA, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
    $pdo1->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
    $pdo2 = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_SERVER.';dbname='.DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
    $pdo2->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
    try {
    foreach ($pdo1->query("SELECT 
                            count(DISTINCT postnr) as pstnr,
                            postnr as postnumret
                        FROM XXX") as $row) {
                            $count = $row['pstnr'];
                            $postnumret = $row['postnumret'];
            $result = $pdo2->prepare("UPDATE YYY
                                        SET a1_ant = '$count' 
                                        WHERE postnummer = $postnumret");
            $result->execute();
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e) {  
     echo $e->getMessage(); 
}
```

I'm using php, pdo and mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you are looking for a query or not. But using below sql query you can do the same.

```
update tab2 set 
count = 
(select count(postnr) 
 from table1 
 where postnr = tab2.postnr 
 )
```

See a demo fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/04d586/1

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do this just by a query no need to write down the code. 
Have a look at [this sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/89a90/2) i made for you.

```
select val, count(val) from t1 group by val;
insert into t2 
select val as vals, count(val) as int from t1 group by val;

select * from t2;
```